# Draw line - line is not visible

Tags: java, graphics, line, draw, paintcomponent

im trying to connect two JComponents with simple line., here is how i tried to do it:

1st object is filled rectangle, 48x48, and then i have drawed circle(.png) into this rectangle.I placed it on the JPanel, and the X is 106 , and Y is 166

2nd object is filled rectangle 28x57, and its just retangle.. I place this rectangle on JPanel, and its X is 378 and its Y is 180

i have already created the object which represents the line between these two objects, and i set its size like this

```
arcObject.setSize(Math.abs(arcObject.o2.x - arcObject.o1.x), Math.abs(arcObject.o2.y - arcObject.o1.y));
```

I printed the width and the height, and its
272 x 14
, then i add this arcObject on JPanel, call repaint, and the overriden paintComponent in ArcObject class is called.

this is the code

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(o1.x, o1.y, o2.x, o2.y);
}
```

where o1 represents the first object, and the o2 represents the second object (i described these obects at the beggining of this post)

However NO line is visible after paintComponent() is called, when i set arcObject dimensions to some big constant numbers, like 600x600, then it is visible...

So, could you tell me what am i doing wrong ?  :-/ (paintComponent is called for sure, it just does not paint anything, or anything visible)

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to set the location of your arcLine component, and given the way you are handling this, the line really needs to go from arcLine (0,0) to arcLine(width,height)

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on `g.drawLine()` and then run the code in your debugger. Step into `drawLine()` to make sure a) the method is actually called and b) the coordinates are what you expect.